# Allow users to specify offset / timestamp to configure starting point for Event Hub

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, offset, azure-eventhub

I am using an Event Hub Trigger using JAVA.

```
@FunctionName("XXXX")
public void myfunction( 
@EventHubTrigger(name = "msg",eventHubName = "xxxxx",connection = "xxx",consumerGroup = "xxx")                   List<String> data,final ExecutionContext context) throws Exception {
}
```

I need a way to start from previous/old offset/sequence number/datetime. In the Azure function, where should we specify, to control from which timestamp/sequence number, it should start reading from the event hub?

Answer (score 0):

`EventPosition` class defines the position of an `EventData` in the Event Hub partition. The position can be an offset, sequence number, or enqueued time.

Reference: [EventPosition Class - Azure SDK for Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.models.eventposition?view=azure-java-stable)

Here are some code examples in Java as well related to `EventPosition`: [EventPosition - Java Code Examples](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventPosition)